# Mac Numbers: How to identify cells that match a range of cells from another table?

Tags: numbers

I have two sets of data on two sheets both including customer reference numbers, some of which match. I am trying to run a formula to identify every row in Sheet 2 where the customer reference number is also found on Sheet 1.

I can compare like for like cells but I can't seem to set a range for comparison i.e. Does Sheet 2 Cell B2 match any of Sheet 1 cells C2, C3, C4....C400.

Hope the above makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Match()](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/match-ffa59a83d3/web) function to check if a value exists in at least one cell within a certain range of cells.

Pls let us know if the information provided at the Apple Support page for this function is not enough for you or if you have any other questions. In such a case, it might be better if you also provide screenshot(s) of your data and what you want to eventually achieve (you may just do it manually as an example if necessary).